# How to hide div class in css

Tags: html, css

> On clicking submit button how to hide the below div class. I have tried >with div id but div class is not working as exactly as div id. As I have
>   written the code but It was closing entire window. Below is the code without adding jquery.

```
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-32 w3-padding-large" id="contact">
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:600px">
    <h4 class="w3-center"><b>Please fill the form to continue</b></h4>

    <script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>

    <!--Update the URL for thank you page on form submit -->
    <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;"
    onload="if(submitted) {window.location='';}"></iframe>

    <!-- Update the Google forms URL in action-->
    <form class= 'form1' action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/a/1FAIlQLDFDHBaSVqkaf1BLTQ1MeRa1NH8OGw4Tpj_SZUvRj-QUTYu9Qw/formResponse" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="return validateForm(); ">


      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" required name="entry.482263238">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" required name="entry.227786006">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" required name="entry.30499006">
      </div>

      <div class="w3-section">
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-black w3-margin-bottom" type="submit">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of `div`s in your code. Which one do you want to hide? Classes in CSS are used with the [`.`-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) (e.g. `.your-class`). Hiding elements works with [`display: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/display). You have to use javascript to do it "after submitting". This can be done with the [`submit` javascript event](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit) or [`submit` jquery event](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit).

Comment: Hello, Explain it briefly which div you want to hide?

Comment: all those need to be hidden is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to hide the entire form, you can add `form.style.display = "none"` to your `validateForm()` function:

```
const form = document.querySelector(".w3-container");

function validateForm() {

form.style.display = "none";
}
```

The same methodology applies if you want to hide some other div, just select it and apply `element.style.display = "none";`.

JSfiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jpxuz6n5/)

Comment: I suggest using `display: none` over `visibility: hidden`. Hidden visibility will still take up the space so the the page will contain a big white space which looks ugly. Also for page redrawing (which happens almost all the time) and for screen readers `display:none` is a lot better for preformance.

Comment: Agreed, changed to display: none

Comment: @DamjanOstrelic can you solve the same problem but little extended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959024/how-to-display-another-div-after-form-submit-in-chat-window