# How to display another div after form submit in Chat window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created an index html file which has chatwindow which looks likes this.

[image]

At the bottom of submit button there an area to accept text. How to hide that part or disable that part and activate later the form is filled and clicked submit button. I tried to hide the div class but throwing an error.

Here is my html code:

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Chatbot</title>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <!--Import Font Awesome Icon Font-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
         integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />  

      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Main css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">




    <style>
    input[type="date"] {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* create a new arrow, because we are going to mess up the native one
    see "List of symbols" below if you want another, you could also try to add a font-awesome icon.. */
    input[type="date"]:after {
        content: "\25BC";
        color: #555;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }

    /* change color of symbol on hover */
    input[type="date"]:hover:after {
        color: #bf1400;
    }

    /* make the native arrow invisible and stretch it over the whole field so you can click anywhere in the input field to trigger the native datepicker*/
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        color: transparent;
        background: transparent;
    }

    /* adjust increase/decrease button */
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        z-index: 1;
    }

     /* adjust clear button */
     input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
         z-index: 1;
     }

    </style>   


   </head>
   <body>




   <!-- seperate containter -->
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Modal for rendering the charts, declare this if you want to render charts, 
         else you remove the modal -->
         <div id="modal1" class="modal">
            <canvas id="modal-chart"></canvas>
         </div>

        <!--chatbot widget -->
         <div class="widget">
            <div class="chat_header">

               <!--Add the name of the bot here -->
               <span class="chat_header_title">Dima Business&nbsp;Chat</span>
               <span class="dropdown-trigger" href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>
                  <i class="material-icons">
                  more_vert
                  </i>
               </span>


               <!-- Dropdown menu-->
               <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
                  <li><a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="restart">Restart</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="close" >Close</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>

            <!--Chatbot contents goes here -->
            <div class="chats" id="chats">
               <div class="clearfix">

            <!-- this is form code externally added -->
            <!-- Start Contact Section -->

 <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-32 w3-padding-large" id="contact">
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:600px">
    <h4 class="w3-center"><b>Please fill the form to continue</b></h4>

    <script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>

    <!--Update the URL for thank you page on form submit -->
    <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;"
    onload="if(submitted) {window.location='';}"></iframe>

    <!-- Update the Google forms URL in action-->
    <form class= 'form1' action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfDHBaSVqkaf1BLTQ1MeRa1NH8OGw4Tpj_SZUvRj-QUTYu9Qw/formResponse" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="return validateForm(); ">


      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" required name="entry.482263238">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" required name="entry.227926006">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" required name="entry.30319006">
      </div>

      <div class="w3-section">
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-black w3-margin-bottom" type="submit">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>               

            <!-- end of the form code externally added -->

            </div>
            </div>

            <!--keypad for user to type the message -->
            <div class="keypad">
               <textarea id="userInput" placeholder="Type a message..." class="usrInput"></textarea>
               <div id="sendButton"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <!--bot profile-->
         <div class="profile_div" id="profile_div">
            <img class="imgProfile" src="static/img/RestoBotAvatar.png" />
         </div>
      </div>

      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

      <!--Main Script -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/script.js"></script>

      <!--Chart.js Script -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/chart.min.js"></script>

   </body>
<footer>





    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateName() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            if(name.length == 0) {
              alert("Name can't be blank") ;
              return false;

            }
            if (!name.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(?: [a-zA-Z]+){0,2}$/)) {
              alert("Please enter your correct name") ;//Validation Message
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          }

          function validatePhone() {
            var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
            if(phone.length == 0) {
              alert("Phone number can't be blank") ;//Validation Message
              return false;
            }

            if(!phone.match(/^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/)) {
             alert("Please enter a correct phone number") ;//Validation Message
             return false;
           }

           return true;

         }

         function validateEmail () {

          var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
          if(email.length == 0) {
            alert("Email can't be blank") ;//Validation Message
            return false;

          }

          if(!email.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-[0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
            alert("Please enter a correct email address") ;//Validation Message
            return false;

          }

          return true;

        }


        function validateForm() {
          if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail()) {

            alert("Form not submitted");//Validation Message
            return false;
          }
          else {
            submitted=true;
            return true;
          }
        }
        </script>
        <script>
        const form = document.querySelector(".w3-container");


function validateForm() {

form.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
        </script>



<!-- End Contact Section -->

</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would approach this is to first select the textarea element you want to hide/disable with `const textarea = document.querySelector("#userInput");`.

Now that you have it selected, you can disable it with: `textarea.disabled = true;` (this will cause it to show on the page but without the possibility to interact with it).

Or, you can completely hide it with `textarea.style.display = "none";`.

Then, you can make your `validateForm` function enable/display it back (once the form has been submitted):

```
    function validateForm() {
              if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail()) {
                alert("Form not submitted"); //Validation Message
                return false;
              } else {
                submitted = true;
                form.style.display = "none";

                textarea.disabled = false;
                textarea.style.display = "inline-block";

                return true;
              }
            }
```

Full code:

```
    const textarea = document.querySelector("#userInput"); //select the textarea element
    textarea.disabled = true; //disable it
    textarea.style.display = "none"; //or completely hide it

    function validateForm() {
      if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail()) {
        alert("Form not submitted"); //Validation Message
        return false;
      } else {
        submitted = true;
        form.style.display = "none";
        textarea.disabled = false; //enable it back
        textarea.style.display = "inline-block"; //or display it back
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's working exactly as I required but the thing is once the submit button is pressed chat window also closes and again if opened new form is appearing with text area hidden.

Comment: When I don't add above script it works good but when I add above script the chat window is closing how to solve it.

Comment: That's because of this line further up in your <iframe> code: "onload="if(submitted) {window.location=''";}". Your validateForm() function sets submitted to "true" so your form reloads. If you remove that, it should work.